# My PlayStation account doesn't link to Ubisoft account

Tags: steam, psn, ubisoft-connect, rainbow-six-siege

I play Rainbow Six Siege (R6) on PC with steam (that I had linked it to my Ubisoft account before), but now I want to link a PlayStation account to my Ubisoft account, and I did it so. But when I open the game, that steam account exists (not my PlayStation account).

Comment: Open the game on what platform?

Comment: on PC. it will open steam first, and then the game